# IntelliJ IDEA ** warning on every line

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

So, as of a couple days ago, IntelliJ IDEA started doing something really weird:

It puts `**` at the end of every line, in the same way it would put a warning on a line. (screenshot below)

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? I don't have any particularly weird plugins installed, just Vi mode and a couple of language support packs.

This is IntelliJ IDEA community edition, version 14.1.4.

Thanks!